# set imagesize in tableview cell dynamically

Tags: objective-c

I am using sdwebimage  in tableview controller, I am getting photos from url, storing urls in array and displaying in imageview in table view cell so how can I set  image size dynamically depends on size of images in tableviewcell in objective-c?.

Answer (score 0):

Read about these two delegates methods of table view and override according to your requirement.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

https://github.com/jurezove/dynamic-uitableviewcells/tree/master